# Chain scopes between models in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm having some trouble querying between models in Rails. I have a class `Message` that `belongs_to: booking`. My goal is to add an `active` scope to `Message` that depends on a `Booking` scope.

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :event
  has_many :messages

  def self.active
    includes(:event).
      where('events.endtime >= ? AND status IS NOT ?'
            Time.current.beginning_of_week,            
            statuses['canceled'])
  end
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :booking
  belongs_to :person

  self.active(person_id)
    where(person_id: person_id).merge(Booking.active)
  end
end
```

I want to find the `Message`s directed to a specific `Person` where the associated `Booking` is `active`. I therefore wish to use the `Booking.active` when creating `Message.active`.

Calling `Message.active(1)` with above implementation returns the following error:

`Association named 'event' was not found on Message; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Is there any way I can use `Booking.active` in the implementation of `Message.active` and get `Message`s returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding conditions on associations, you also need to **join them**, not only `merge` or `include` them, i.e. the following should work:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def self.active
    joins(:event).
      where('events.endtime >= ? AND status IS NOT ?'
          Time.current.beginning_of_week,            
          statuses['canceled'])
  end
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  self.active(person_id)
    where(person_id: person_id).joins(:booking).merge(Booking.active)
  end    
end
```

There is not much documentation on this, see  [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge) for more info.